# Is My Cactus Doing Well?

Tags: houseplants, cactus

My wife and I are a bit concerned with the appearance changes of our cactus. The plant was always growing fast, however the spring accelerated the growth even more. Some time ago we noticed the twisted "stems". First time after the plant was watered, the stems straightened up, but in a few days got curly-ish again. The next time the plant was watered no positive changes were noticed.

A few questions arise:

- Is it normal?
- Is it dangerous?
- What causes it?
- What do we do now?

[image: da plant]

Comment: I'm not sure, but the long skinny sections might indicate it could use more sunlight...

Comment: Have you done anything else to it besides water it (e.g. fertilize it)? What was the interval between waterings? I might suspect it could use some potassium (to help it absorb more water) or less nitrogen (if it's getting too much; too much nitrogen without enough potassium may make plants floppier), but I'm not a cactus expert at this time, and I don't know what species it is, or how normal this is.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a happy cactus.  Shoot.  Have to know anything and everything that you did differently before this occurred.  Did you fertilize?  If so with what?  How much?  How often?  Did you add any other types of 'FOOD' such as bone meal, fish emulsion?  Was this cactus allowed out of doors for a time with the possibility of too cold temperatures?  Is this soil potting soil?  Potting soil made for cactus?  Or is this soil from your garden?

This is an east facing window?  How long has this cactus been in this spot?  Are you using tap water?  How often do you water?  How deeply?  Do you water so deeply that water fills that saucer?  Is there a layer of gravel/rocks/packing peanuts placed beneath the soil and above the drain hole in an effort to improve drainage (NOT a good thing btw).

Allowing this plant's pot to sit in water after watering will definitely compromise the root system with way too much water.  Cactus and succulents are mostly killed by overwatering, next would be using garden soil, next would be over fertilization and next would be not enough light.

You might be able to start parts of this cactus in fresh new potting soil but something has happened that looks irreversible.  Bummer.  Send more information so that we can help you at least learn what went wrong so as not to repeat.  Nothing you've done with this plant is too small to mention.

Better picture to be able to see the true colors and more detail.